# On heterogenous lists, is it possible to make the zip and then unzip equal to the original?

Tags: f#

I am talking about the zip operations in the context of heterogeneous lists. I am working on a lightly dependently typed language that uses them as tuples.

```
type T =
| S of string
| R of T list

let rec zip l =
    let is_all_r_empty x = List.forall (function R [] -> true | _ -> false) x
    let rec loop acc_total acc_head acc_tail x =
        match x with
        | S _ :: _ -> R l
        | R [] :: ys -> 
            if List.isEmpty acc_head && is_all_r_empty ys then List.rev acc_total |> R 
            else R l
        | R (x :: xs) :: ys -> loop acc_total (x :: acc_head) (R xs :: acc_tail) ys
        | [] -> 
            match acc_tail with
            | _ :: _ -> loop ((List.rev acc_head |> zip) :: acc_total) [] [] (List.rev acc_tail)
            | _ -> List.rev acc_total |> R
    loop [] [] [] l

let rec unzip l =
    let transpose l =
        let is_all_empty x = List.forall (function _ :: _ -> false | _ -> true) x
        let rec loop acc_total acc_head acc_tail = function
            | (x :: xs) :: ys -> loop acc_total (x :: acc_head) (xs :: acc_tail) ys
            | [] :: ys -> 
                if List.isEmpty acc_head && is_all_empty ys then loop acc_total acc_head acc_tail ys 
                else l
            | [] ->
                match acc_tail with
                | _ :: _ -> loop (List.rev acc_head :: acc_total) [] [] (List.rev acc_tail)
                | _ -> List.rev acc_total
        loop [] [] [] l
    let is_all_r x = List.forall (function R _ -> true | _ -> false) x
    match l with
    | R x when is_all_r x -> List.map unzip x |> transpose |> List.map R
    | R x -> x
    | S _ -> failwith "Unzip called on S."

//let a = R [R [S "a"; S "t"]; R [S "b"; S "w"]; R [S "c"; S "e"]]
//let b = R [R [S "1"; S "4"]; R [S "5"; S "r"]; R [S "3"; S "6"]]
//let c = R [R [S "z"; S "v"]; R [S "x"; S "b"]; R [S "c"; S "2"]]
//
//let t3 = zip [a;b]
//let t4 = zip [t3;c]
//let u1 = unzip t4
//let r1 = u1 = [t3;c]
//let u2 = unzip t3
//let r2 = u2 = [a;b] // The above works fine on tuples with regular dimensions.

let a = R [R [S "q"; S "w"; S "e"]]
let b = R [R [S "a"; S "s"]; R [S "z"]; S "wqe"]
let ab = [a;b]
let t = zip ab
let t' = unzip t
ab = t' // This is false, but I would like the ziping and then unziping to be reversible if possible.
```

Zipping and unzipping in general can be expressed as a dimensional shift or a series of transposes. That is all these two functions are doing.

They behave well on regular tuples, but I would like zip+unzip to be isomorphic on irregular ones as well. My intuition is telling me that this would be asking too much of them though.

I need a second opinion here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#r "../../packages/FsCheck.2.8.0/lib/net452/FsCheck.dll"

type T =
| S of string
| VV of T list

let transpose l on_fail on_succ =
    let is_all_vv_empty x = List.forall (function VV [] -> true | _ -> false) x
    let rec loop acc_total acc_head acc_tail = function
        | VV [] :: ys -> 
            if List.isEmpty acc_head && is_all_vv_empty ys then 
                if List.isEmpty acc_total then failwith "Empty inputs in the inner dimension to transpose are invalid."
                else List.rev acc_total |> on_succ
            else on_fail ()
        | VV (x :: xs) :: ys -> loop acc_total (x :: acc_head) (VV xs :: acc_tail) ys
        | _ :: _ -> on_fail ()
        | [] -> 
            match acc_tail with
            | _ :: _ -> loop (VV (List.rev acc_head) :: acc_total) [] [] (List.rev acc_tail)
            | _ -> List.rev acc_total |> on_succ
    loop [] [] [] l

let rec zip l = 
    match l with
    | _ :: _ -> transpose l (fun _ -> l) (List.map (function VV x -> zip x | x -> x)) |> VV
    | _ -> failwith "Empty input to zip is invalid."

let rec unzip l = 
    let is_all_vv x = List.forall (function VV _ -> true | _ -> false) x
    match l with
    | VV x ->
        match x with
        | _ :: _ when is_all_vv x -> let t = List.map (unzip >> VV) x in transpose t (fun _ -> x) id
        | _ :: _ -> x
        | _ -> failwith "Empty inputs to unzip are invalid."
    | S _ -> failwith "Unzip called on S."

open FsCheck
open System

let gen_t =
    let mutable gen_t = None
    let gen_s () = Gen.map S Arb.generate<string>
    let gen_vv size = Gen.nonEmptyListOf (gen_t.Value size) |> Gen.map VV
    gen_t <- 
        fun size -> 
            match size with
            | 0 -> gen_s()
            | _ when size > 0 -> Gen.oneof [gen_s (); gen_vv (size-1)] 
            | _ -> failwith "impossible" 
        |> Some
    gen_t.Value
    |> Gen.sized

let gen_t_list_irregular = Gen.nonEmptyListOf gen_t
let gen_t_list_regular = Gen.map2 List.replicate (Gen.choose(1,10)) gen_t

type MyGenerators =
    static member Tuple() = Arb.fromGen gen_t
    static member TupleList() = Arb.fromGen gen_t_list_regular
Arb.register<MyGenerators>()

let zip_and_unzip orig = zip orig |> unzip
let zip_and_unzip_eq_orig orig = zip_and_unzip orig = orig

// For regular tuples it passes with flying colors.

Check.One ({Config.Quick with EndSize = 10}, zip_and_unzip_eq_orig)

// I can't get it to be isomorphic for irregularly sized arrays as expected.

//let f x = 
//    let x' = zip x
//    printfn "x'=%A" x'
//    printfn "unzip x'=%A" (unzip x')
//    printfn "zip_and_unzip_eq_orig x=%A" (zip_and_unzip_eq_orig x)
//
//f [VV [VV [S "12"; S "qwe"]; VV [S "d"]]; VV [VV [S ""; S "ug"]; VV [S ""]]]
```

No matter what, I try I cannot figure out how to make the pair isomorphic for irregularly sized tuples and I feel it is unlikely that anyone will tell me differently so I'll put the above attempt as an answer for now.

On the upside, based on the tests above, I am decently sure that it should be isomorphic for all regularly sizes tuples. I guess this should suffice. I've tightened the code up a little compared to the example I had in the question.

This irregular zipping and unzipping problem would make an interesting math puzzle.